# How to Clear Cache on build for React Apps

Tags: reactjs, caching, deployment, build, browser-cache

I want to clear the cache of browser after every deployment .I tried many libraries and code snipped but nothing is working .I also tried with https://dev.to/ammartinwala52/clear-cache-on-build-for-react-apps-1k8j but after setting up all the things according to this blog nothing is rendering on the screen. Please someone give me the proper solution about this issue.

Comment: You can't clear the client's browser cache, instead, you should properly use [cache headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control) so that the browser knows when to invalidate cached resources.

Comment: You can try the approach I am using, and it works https://dev.to/mnathani/how-to-cache-bust-frontend-app-132l